# Manipulating MTU size in IPTables with mangle for use with OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, iptables, mtu, throughput

I am looking for any and all pointers in regards to modifying or resetting MTU size with the mangle table in iptables. Specifically where in the iptables flow is it more efficient to modify MTU to increase throughput?

I have an OpenVPN server and have identified a bottleneck issue. Gone through the motions with the server/client.conf files and wanted to look into this next, but am pretty green when it comes to iptables.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally MTU is connected to an interface and manipulated with either `ifconfig` or `ip link`. Why do you want to set the MTU using iptables?

Comment: attempting to troubleshoot a significant loss of throughput we are seeing when the OpenVPN connection is up. I think the logic was to try and adjust the payload as packets are added in the tunnel from the hops on the network

Comment: Is the traffic, that looses throughput going through the VPN? What characteristics of the traffic change when it looses throughput? I don't see the connection to the MTU.

Comment: Yes. Lets say we have a tunnel set up point A to B...using throughput test/download/iperf etc. we see throughput of X - lets say 10Mbps . Traffic passing that same A to B with OpenVPN up in 1/4 or less the speed of X - 2Mbps or less. I am kind of throwing darts to see what sticks in regards to iptables and mangle as all other troubleshooting has proven fruitless.

Comment: A VPN needs additional protocol overhead that depends on the kind of VPN you use. You can't make this go away by manipulating the MTU. But when the traffic only reaches 1/4 of the throughput as without VPN, you should look for other things than MTU. Can you post the configuration of the VPN? Do you use OpenVPN with TCP? Is it possible that your VPN gateway is not able to handle the traffic?